# Dialog box in programs using JOptionPane and JFrame is not showing what's in my code

Tags: java, swing, fonts

The dialog box is showing everything one character ahead according to ASCII, having the same problem while running the program through dos.

Please someone help me out!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

class MyFirstGUI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        System.out.println(UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getName());
        String first = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first number");
        String second = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second number");

        int n = Integer.parseInt(first);
        int m = Integer.parseInt(second);
        int sum = n + m;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sum = "+sum, "Sum of 2 numbers", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    }  
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code (besides the fact that you start you GUI outside the EDT)? If I type '1' and then '2', it says that the sum is '3'

Comment: The problem is that instead of displaying "Enter the first number" in the dialog box,its displaying "Foufs uif gjstu ovncfs" and that too in some weird manner..I can't upload a pic otherwise i would've by now to make myself clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I get from running your code (with 1 and 5):

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

So there must be something else. Have you make sure that your class files are up-to-date?

Comment: Ya,everything is up to date.Its just some problem with my fonts..I need some help with fonts in dialog boxes.

Comment: You can call this before anything else: `UIManager.getDefaults().put("OptionPane.messageFont", aFont);`. This will override the default font of JOptionPane.

Comment: What are the fonts that i can set?

Comment: @shiri4frnz I think that Lucida is one of the font that is always available in any JVM. Otherwise, you can always perform a lookup of the available Fonts on GraphicsEnvironment with the method getAllFonts.

Comment: I too have LucidaSansRegular but i am unable to set it.Care to show me the syntax in the method you mentioned.

Comment: @shiri4frnz `UIManager.getDefaults().put("OptionPane.messageFont", new Font("Lucida Sans Regular", Font.PLAIN, 12));`.

Comment: Half way through due to you @Guillaume Polet. Now its just the 'Input', 'OK', and 'Cancel' that are in that weird manner.Whatever i am typing and the line 'Enter the first number' is being displayed correctly.So,i'd be obliged to be helped further.Anyway, thanks for the help!!